# Existence of a positive definite matrix which satisfies an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, positive-definite

While doing control analysis, I've bumped into a mathematical problem that looks like below:

$Au = b(u)$

Under what conditions of $b,u$ (both are a $3 \times 1$ vector) that there exists a positive-definite matrix $A$ (a $3 \times 3$ matrix) which satisfies the above equation? Vector $b$ is a function of $u$, which in turns, $u$ may be constrained by the condition $||u||<u_{max}$. I'm really not strong in mathematics, and I don't know where to get started. I thought I will write every component of $A$ and solve for a bunch of inequalities (maybe using Sylvester criterion) but I wonder whether it could be done more efficiently.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do some reading on Eigen values and Eigen vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've read some but most of the properties can be inferred from an already existing matrix A. Now it seems like I have to construct that matrix A in order to prove its existence. Would you mind showing me which specific part of eigenvalues and eigenvectors should I read? Many thanks!

Comment: It reads as if $A$ only needs to be able to satisfy the equation for one $u$. If that is the case: If $u=0$ then $b(u)$ should be $=0$. Then any positive-definite (PD) matrix $A$ works. If $b(u)=0$, then $u$ must be $=0$, and then any PD matrix works. If $u,b(u)\neq0$, then you need that the dot product $u^T\cdot b(u)>0$. In that case, there is always a PD matrix $A$ such that $Au=b(u)$. To find one, complete $u$ to an orthonormal basis $u,e_2,e_3$, and also complete $b(u)$ to an orthonormal basis $b(u),f_2,f_3$. Then $A=[b(u),f_2,f_3]\cdot [u,e_2,e_3]^T$ works, where the brackets are ...

Comment: ... the matrices formed by putting those vectors in columns.

Comment: Do you need this to hold for *all* vectors $u$ (in which case $b(u)$ must be a linear function of $u$) or just for *one* particular vector $u$?

Comment: I think for my problem, $u$ is some vector and the only constraint I could put on it is to make $||u|| < u_{max}$. Nevertheless, if $u$ is any vector then the controller is more robust, but I think it would be impossible to achieve (because physics won't allow such phenomena).

Comment: Thus you want to find a constant PD matrix $A$ that satisfies $Au=b(u)$ for all vectors $u$ such that $\|u\|\le u_\max$. Right?

Comment: Yes. @A.Γ. Sorry for my being lengthy.

Comment: @deyore I'm sorry I don't quite understand the part of the dot product $u^T b(u)>0$. Would that only infer that $A$ is "PD" only for the u we're considering ($u^TAu>0$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, the question is very different if it is for one $u$, than if it is for many $u$. So, my construction of an $A$ was only for the former case, before you edited the question. The condition that $u^Tb(u)=u^TAu>0$, if $u,b(u)\neq0$, is a necessary condition.

Comment: @deyore Thanks for your reply. I've just reeditted my question for more clarifications. My bad!

Comment: What kind of function is $b(\cdot)$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen b is a nonlinear function of u, but could be bounded by a norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the conditions that

1. $b(u)=Au$ for some matrix $A$ in some ball around the origin.
2. $A=A^T$.
3. $u^TAu>0$ for all $u\ne 0$.

2 and 3 means that $A$ is positive definite. Now those conditions are equivalent to the following

1. The first condition is equivalent to $b(u)$ being a (locally) linear map, i.e. $b(u+\alpha v)=b(u)+\alpha b(v)$, for all $u$, $v$ and $w=u+\alpha v$ that satisfy the norm bound. The matrix of the linear map $A$ is defined uniquely (in the given basis).
2. The symmetry is equivalent to $v^TAu=u^TAv$, i.e. $v^Tb(u)=u^Tb(v)$, for all $u$, $v$ in the ball. It is sufficient to test only the basic vectors $e_k$ (vector with all zeros except one identity at the position $k$), that is, $v^Tb(u)=u^Tb(v)$ for $u=\alpha e_i$, $v=\alpha e_j$ for all $i\ne j$, where $\alpha\ne 0$ is a scalar chosen such that $u$, $v$ satisfy the norm bound.
3. $u^Tb(u)>0$ for all $u$ in the ball.

Comment: As you said indeed, for my problem, (3) can be satisfied for all $u$ in some ball $||u||<u_{max}$. I will try to work on the remaining conditions. Thank you so much.